# RedBean: How to delete all rows from all tables

Tags: orm, truncate, redbean

I am using RedBean ORM. In order to create the schema I used the standard redbean approach of inserting data so that Redbean would auto-fit the schema to suit my needs. I put this in a script which would basically be used to build the schema when i need to initialize my database.

The problem is that RedBean keeps a row or 2 in each table (the ones that I initially inserted  to get redbean to build the schema).

If it were a normal database, to erase all rows i would just drop the schema and rebuild it, but in this case that's not possible since the initial rows would still exist.

Unfortunately there isn't too much Redbean Q/A out there. Anyone know how I would do this using the Redbean interface?

I have tried

```
    $listOfTables = R::$writer->getTables();
foreach($listOfTables as $table)
{
    R::wipe($table);
}
```

Of course this doesn't work though. (It doesn't TRUNCATE the tables in the correct order so I get an error about another table using this key as a foreign link. It simply iterates in ABC order)

```
Fatal error: Uncaught [42000] - SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1701 Cannot truncate a table referenced in a foreign key constraint (`redbeandb`.`research`, CONSTRAINT `research_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`ownEducationHistory_id`) REFERENCES `redbeandb`.`educationhistory` (`id`)) thrown in C:\Users\Rod\nginx-1.0.12\html\rb.php on line 105
```

If someone has a (redbean api) solution, it would be much appreciated. And hopefully this question can be beneficial to building up more RedBean Q/A here on Stackoverflow.

Comment: There is always `R::nuke()`, but I think that will destroy all your tables too.  I don't know if you can wipe unless you remove the foreign keys, and I don't know if you can do that simply.

Comment: Relevant part of documentation: https://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/crud#delete

Answer (score 2):

Use

R::nuke();

Yes, it will drop all tables but since RedBeanPHP creates all tables on the fly this is not a problem.

Comment: You would only want to create tables on the fly in a development environment, not on the live site.

Comment: Here is that part of documentation: https://www.redbeanphp.com/index.php?p=/crud#delete

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post but I figured I'd help out someone finding this today.  You can tell mysql to ignore foreign key checks if you don't care about data integrity (plan on wiping all related tables).

```
R::exec('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;');
$listOfTables = R::$writer->getTables();
foreach($listOfTables as $table)
{
    R::wipe($table);
}
R::exec('SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;');
```